# Error using the wrapfigure package

Tags: tables, floats, wrap

I have a problem using `wrapfigure`. I am trying to use the following code:

```
%\begin{figure*}[h!]
\begin{wrapfigure}[r]{0.5\textwidth}
%\centering
\begin{center}
   \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Figures/...JPG} 
\end{center}
\caption{..}
\label{ecg intervals}
\end{wrapfigure}
%\end{figure*}
```

It gives the following error: Package calc Error: \let ' invalid at this point. Missing $ inserted. Use of \WF@rapt doesn't match its definition. Does someone know what is wrong?

Comment: please provide an example that produces the error

Answer (score 1):

The arguments of wrapfig are

```
[number of narrow lines] {placement} [overhang] {width of figure}
```

so the first optional argument should be a number if used but you have `[r]`

try

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
```